# Html: disable all suggestion (copy share search dhe web)

Tags: html, contextmenu

Sometimes on some elements the mobile Android shows a set of 2 blue balloons and if you touch the element, it show a context menu containing paste/share/search the WEB.
. Is it possible to disable this feature on the entire body?

Comment: You can essentially do this using CSS. `pointer-events: none;` more or less makes an element non-interactive, and `user-select: none;` prevents the selection of text (*the 2 blue balloons you mentioned*)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work so far (it happened kind of randomly, so I will wait to be sure). Do you also know how to stop (disable) pop up ads or notifications (like facebook messages, or ads from others). I use the page to interact with my own server in a LAN and this popups are annoying to the user.

Comment: If you mean *popups* as in mobile notifications, then you cannot control that. Other than that I'm not sure what you are referring to. The only *popups* you would be able to control are ones that are generated by a page you control the source code to. And specifically how will depend on how those *popups* are generated by the page.